# nightwatch.js: window switching not working

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am trying to switch to new window in `nightwatch.js` but it is not working. It is giving error : `Time out waiting for element button[class='foo']`.

I have tried:

```
client.switchWindow(function(result) {
            var handle = result.value[0];
            client.switchWindow(handle);
        });
```

I am using `swtichWindow` because `windows_handles(function(result))` is deprecated.

I am using page object model, so I have also tried:

```
profilePage
    .switchWindow(function(result) {
    var handle = result.value[0];
    profilePage.switchWindow(handle);
})
    .verifyOldPic();
```

I am using Windows 7, Google Chrome browser.

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong without the rest of the code. I think the answers in [this thread can help you](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/369).

Comment: Comments over there shows that they have used `windows_handles`, comment made in `Feb 2015`. Does this mean it got deprecated few months ago, if Yes, whats the solution now??